# Using counter in variable name

Tags: javascript

This is what I have currently but I cant get v(i) to behave the same as v1. What am I doing wrong? 
I've also tried the piece below which also did not work.

```
var x = "v" + i;
alert(x);
```

My main problem is the following:

```
var v1 = document.getElementById("thing1").innerHTML; // = 100
var v2 = document.getElementById("thing2").innerHTML; // = 150
var v3 = document.getElementById("thing3").innerHTML; // = 200

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if ( v(i) != ""){
        alert(v(i));
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: why not use an array or an object for it?

Comment: You are calling v as a function when you put parenthesis after it.

Comment: @NinaScholz Could you explain what you mean? I'm a complete novice sorry.

Comment: @ChipDean What should I do then if I want to use 'v' then the counter number?

Comment: See "What is an Array" on [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not easily accomplished. You would have to assign the variable to the window object and then print it from there.

A much better solution is to use your own object or array to handle this:

```
var v1 = document.getElementById("thing1").innerHTML; // = 100
var v2 = document.getElementById("thing2").innerHTML; // = 150
var v3 = document.getElementById("thing3").innerHTML; // = 200
var array = [v1,v2,v3];
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if ( array[i] != ""){
        alert(array[i]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array without using single variables and loop it.

```js
var array = [
        '100', // document.getElementById("thing1").innerHTML,
        '150', // document.getElementById("thing2").innerHTML,
        '200'  // document.getElementById("thing3").innerHTML
    ],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] !== "") {
        console.log(array[i]);
    }
}
```

If you need some keys, you could use an object.

```js
var object = {
        v1: '150', // document.getElementById("thing1").innerHTML,
        v2: '200', // document.getElementById("thing2").innerHTML,
        v3: '250', // document.getElementById("thing3").innerHTML
    },
    i;

for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (object['v' + i] !== "") {
        console.log(object['v' + i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All global variables are properties of `window` object you could use `window['v'+ i]` or `this['v'+ i]` to create them.
But this is very bad pattern consider using object instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is get an interpolated variable name, which is not possible in javascript the way you do it.

You can do this using `this['v'+i]` or `window['v'+i]` which are both bad ideas in the global scope.

`v(i)` actually means: *run function `v(...)` with parameter `i`*

If i would write your example code in easy to understand javascript, i would come up with this:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    var html = document.getElementById('thing'+i).innerHTML;
    alert(html);
}
```

If you want your values in an array, in a way that you don't write the same code 6 times:

```
var ids = ['thing1','thing2','thing3','thing4'];

// es5
  var values = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
  {
     var html = document.getElementById( ids[i] ).innerHTML;
     values.push( html );
  }
  // values now contains all the values of the elements

// OR es 6
  var values = ids.map(function(id) { return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML; });
  // or
  var values = ids.map(id => document.getElementById(id).innerHTML);
```